# Files reappearing instantly after deleting

Tags: filesystems, xfce, manjaro, readonly, access-control

Initially, I had the issue of `Cannot remove fileX Read-only filesystem` and referred [this](https://serverfault.com/a/304418) thread which removed that problem but raised other, rather peculiar, problem; when I deleted the files from the command line, they got removed, but as soon as reentered the folder, they reappeared instantly, every time. What is happening?

PS: The files are on different partition (Windows partition actually), the corresponding output of `cat /proc/mounts` is

```
/dev/sda5 / ext4 rw,noatime 0 0
/dev/sda4 /run/media/mehul/New\040Volume fuseblk rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

And Manjaro is on sda5.

The path of the files is

```
/run/media/mehul/New Volume/Documents/College/STUDIES/Japanese/
```

The files are PPTs.

Comment: What are these files, something you've originally created? Where are they located (directory path and filenames)? Are they associated with any cron job? There are malware that does similar things by downloading their code at regular intervals. If you think you have an intruder on your system, you should swing by ServerFault and read https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Edited the question @Kusalananda

Comment: Are you dual-booting with Windows? If so disable Fast Startup in Windows.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia it solved my issue. Fast-boot was the issue apparently. Thank you.